# Install Perl CPAN Net::LibIDN on Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: perl, cpan, osx-yosemite

After upgrade to OS X 10.10 all CPAN Perl modules have been deleted and I faced a problem with installing Net::LibIDN:

```
sudo cpan -i Net::LibIDN
...
CPAN.pm: Building T/TH/THOR/Net-LibIDN-0.12.tar.gz
__test1.c:1:10: fatal error: 'idna.h' file not found
```

But I have already installed libidn with homebrew:

```
locate libidn
/usr/local/Library/Formula/libidn.rb
/usr/local/lib/libidn.11.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libidn.a
/usr/local/lib/libidn.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libidn.la
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libidn.pc
/usr/local/share/info/libidn-components.png
/usr/local/share/info/libidn.info
```

And:

```
locate idna.h
/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/52.1/include/unicode/idna.h
/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/52.1/include/unicode/uidna.h
/usr/local/include/idna.h
```

How can I install this CPAN library and tell CPAN.pm builder where this header file is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build this manually in this case, as stated in the [README](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/THOR/Net-LibIDN2-0.03/README):

---

If your local version of GNU Libidn2 is installed in a non-standard
location, try the following instead of "perl Build.PL":

```
 perl Build.PL --extra_compiler_flags=-I/path/include --extra_linker_flags="-L/path/lib -lidn2"
```

Should your runtime library search path not contain libidn2, you
probably will have to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH or compile the absolute
library path into the module like follows:

```
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/lib perl Build.PL --extra_compiler_flags=-I/path/include --extra_linker_flags="-L/path/lib -lidn2"
```

or

```
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/lib perl Build.PL --extra_compiler_flags=-I/path/include --extra_linker_flags="-L/path/lib -lidn2 -Wl,-rpath=/path/lib"
```

Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH *and* rpath might be necessary to make
Devel::CheckLib detect the presence of libidn2 correctly.

Comment: TY for good advice but README has been changed alitle. The way is the same but now the command is perl Makefile.PL --with-libidn=/usr/local/lib --with-libidn-inc=/usr/local/include --disable-tld for my case. To install libidn with homebrew after update this is helpfull http://jcvangent.com/fixing-homebrew-os-x-10-10-yosemite/